# Is there syntax for adding a clue to ScalaTest matchers?

Tags: scala, scalatest

Is there an idiom for adding a clue to a ScalaTest matcher such that the clue will become part of the assertion failure? I know that I can currently write a ScalaTest assertion like this:

```
withClue("expecting a header row and 3 rows of data") {
  rowCount should equal(4)
}
```

Is this the only syntax for adding the clue to the assertion? It would be nice to be able write an assertion to look something like this:

```
rowCount should equal(4) because("expecting a header row and 3 rows of data")
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you mixin `AppendedClues` you can write the `withClue` as a suffix:

```
class TestSuite extends FlatSpec with Matchers with AppendedClues {
  3 should equal(4) withClue("expecting a header row and 3 rows of data")
}
```

Also works without parens of course.

Comment: Nice. Some mention of this should be added to the "Using Matchers" section of the ScalaTest User Guide.